# How to deactivate the alpha "color" of a layout with an on touch listener

Tags: java, android, xml, popup, popupwindow

Hello I created a quiz app, there on the second java class (Menu2) is a Button, If someone clicks on this button a pop up window appears and the background(the Layout of Menu2) gets an alpha/transparency of 0.1. When someone clicks **IN THE POPUPWINDOW** the popup window close it self and the transparency will be set to **1**. But if somene clicks outside the pop up, the pop up closes but the transparency lasts... How can I fix that?

menu2:

```
        public class Menu2 extends AppCompatActivity {




private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout2;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private Button popup;
private PopupWindow popupWindow;private LayoutInflater layoutInflater; //Alows to add a new layout in our window



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu2);


     TextView txtScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScore2);
     TextView txtHighScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textHighScore);
     ImageView imgTrophyView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trophy1);
     ImageView imgTrophyView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trophy2);
     TextView trophy1Txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.trophy1Text);
     TextView trophy2Txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.trophy2Text);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int mScore = intent.getIntExtra ("score",0);
    txtScore.setText("Your score is: " + mScore);

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int applyView =sharedpreferences.getInt("currentscore",0);


    SharedPreferences mypref =getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int highScore = mypref.getInt("highScore", 0);
    if (highScore>= mScore)
        txtHighScore.setText("High score: " + highScore);


    else{
        txtHighScore.setText("New highscore: " + mScore);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();
        editor.putInt("highScore",mScore);
        editor.commit();

    }

    if (applyView >=10) {
        imgTrophyView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        trophy1Txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
        if (applyView >= 20){
            imgTrophyView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            trophy2Txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    popup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enablePOPUP);
    popup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_menu2_1,null);
            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container,1000,980,true); //400,400=popUp size, true = makes that we can close the pop up by simply click out of the window
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(mDrawerLayout2, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            mDrawerLayout2.setAlpha((float) 0.1);

            container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

                @Override

                        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent  ){
                        mDrawerLayout2.setAlpha((float) 1);
                              popupWindow.dismiss();

                        return true;

                }
            });
        }
    });





    mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mDrawerLayout2 = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout2);

    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout2, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout2.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(nv2);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case(R.id.nav_home2):
                    Intent accountActivity2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),QuizActivity.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity2);

            }
            return true;
        }
    });}

            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Menu2.this, QuizActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

}




@Override //Makes that the "Burger" Item, shows the Drawer if someone clicks on the simbol
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


}
```

}

Menu2 XML:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="amapps.impossiblequiz.Menu2"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout2">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <include
        layout="@layout/navigation_action"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trophy2Text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="20 points= High knowledge"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/trophy1Text"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trophy2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trophy2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/trophy2"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/trophy2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textScore2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#f60"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:text="Your score is:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textHighScore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#FFAB00"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:paddingRight="100dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Highest score:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textScore2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tryAgain_button"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_pill"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Restart Quiz!"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textHighScore"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
            android:text="Stats: play and get trophies!"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/trophy1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tryAgain_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/trophy1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/trophy2"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/trophy1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/trophy1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/trophy1"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/trophy2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trophy1Text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="10 points= Basic intelligence"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_below="@+id/trophy1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trophy1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trophy1"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/trophy2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/trophy2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/statsTrophy"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/statsoftrophy"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textHighScore"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tryAgain_button"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/enablePOPUP"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/trophy2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu2"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/nv2"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/tint_color_selector2">




</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try do this:

```
popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDismiss() {
        mDrawerLayout2.setAlpha((float) 1);
        popup.dismiss();

    }
});
```